# I am trying to copy my javascript code into add url option in chrome, but as soon as it enter '[' the save options get freezed

Tags: javascript

```
javascript.function E(){ f0=document.forms[0];
f0['username'].value]='abhiking'; 
}E()
```

So i wanted this code to be autofill to one of the form

Comment: remove ] after value i.e `value='abhiking';`

Comment: Still its not working

Answer (score 0):

You need to use colon after javascript like follows:

```
javascript:(function(){ document.forms[0]['username'].value='abhiking'; })();
```

Also you need to make sure that the form you want to fill is the first form in the document.